# Bootstrap dropdown button menu disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Ruby on Rails (Rails Tutorial Sample App). In my app, a user can like ("savor") microposts ("pops"). When there are more than zero likes on a post, I want the '# likes' display button to display the Gravatar icons of the liking users in a dropdown menu. I have it more or less working. However, when I click on the button and the dropdown opens, it closes automatically within a few seconds. I want it to stay open until the user clicks on one of the thumbnails or somewhere else on the page (or on the button again). None of the examples I've looked at (none of which have this problem) use image thumbnails in this way, and usually just have ordered lists in the dropdown. Am I going about this correctly, or is there a better way?

In addition, I am a complete n00b when it comes to implementing javascript/jQuery. I understand the code, but I can never figure out where I need to put it and where I need to mention/require it to get my code working. So if there is a javascript/jQuery fix for this, please let me know exactly where it needs to go.

NOTE: this is different from another issue that's been asked before, where the dropdown menu disappears when you click on it. If I'm quick, I can click on the thumbnail and visit the link just fine. The problem is that the menu usually disappears after a few seconds, before I can click on anything (and while I have my cursor on it). This is especially frustrating on mobile, because the dropdown always closes right as you're about to tap a thumbnail.

**_micropost.html.erb**

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.picture.url if micropost.picture? %>
  </span>

  <span class="timestamp">
    Popped <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    <span class="dropdown">
      <% if micropost.likers(User).count == 0 %>
        <div id="like">
          <%= pluralize(micropost.likers(User).count, "savor", "savors") %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="btn-group"> //button dropdown
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <%= pluralize(micropost.likers(User).count, "savor", "savors") %>
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="user_avatars dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <% micropost.likers(User).each do |user| %>
              <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <% if current_user.likes?(micropost) %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, "Savored", class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary", disabled: true) %>
      <% elsif (current_user != micropost.user) %>
        <%= link_to 'Savor', micropost, action: :update, method: :put, class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
      <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
        <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                         data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </span>
</li>
```

**from custom.css.scss**

```
.user_avatars {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  .gravatar {
    margin: 1px 1px;
  }
  a {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, the post form was set to refresh every 5000 milliseconds, so it kept closing the menu. Changed it to 30000 (30 seconds) and everything's working fine.

**The Culprit (_feed.html.erb)**

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts" id="refreshable">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>

<!--make feed refreshable -->
<script>
  setInterval( function() {
    $("#refreshable").load(location.href+" #refreshable>*", "");
  }, 30000);
</script>
```